# how to get digital signatures between two participants, rest can see only ledger update without getting signatures?

Tags: corda

I am using three nodes let say A, B, C and doing transaction between A & B. But I would like to make that transaction visible to C without getting any digital signature? if that possible using subflow means,how to define?

Comment: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-observer-nodes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of required signers for a transaction is completely separate from the set of parties who see the transaction as part of `FinalityFlow` (the `participants`).

The required signers are defined by the union of all the public keys on all the commands in the transaction, and not by the union of all the `participants` in all the transaction's input and output states.

As Kid101 points out, you can also use the observer nodes functionality (see the tutorial [here](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-observer-nodes.html) and the Observable States sample [here](https://github.com/corda/observable-states) to distribute the transaction to parties who aren't even `participants` as well.